# Source of the expression that sounds like "Jee-hossey-fat"

Tags: etymology

A refugee American Loyalist, around 1800 or so,  hits his thumb with a hammer and says ''Jee-hossey-fat''  or something like that (my Great Grandfather)   Where does this expression come from please?

Comment: How much research have you done on this? *Jehoshaphat* was the fourth king of Judah. Americans around 1800 knew their bibles. For many it was the only book they would ever possess. Look in 2 Chronicles 17.

Comment: In old time people avoided using real holy terms when cursing (Jesus, Mary etc.) a bit like people saying "Sugar!" instead of "shit". A lot of cursing are deformation of sacred words. In this case your ancestor probably meant "Jesus' faith!"

Comment: @JEL I was doing the same thing for the question to put it back.

Comment: Related: *[What is the origin and meaning of “Save some for Jehoshaphat”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250914)*

Comment: @WS2 - I think the edits changed the character of this question a little.  As shown in the question body (but corrected in the title) the OP was not aware of the actual name, and just rendered it phonetically.  I have changed it back --if you already know what the name is, the question reduces to general reference.

Answer (score 4):

***[Jehoshaphat](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/jehoshaphat)*** is the name of a King of Judah. As an exclamation has probably become popular as a euphemism for Jesus:

> - A king of Judah in the mid 9th century bc.
> - ***As exclamation (also jumping Jehoshaphat)*** *A mild expletive:
>     Jehoshaphat! That would be ghastly
>     (Probably a euphemism for Jesus)*

(ODO)

The biblical king [Jehoshaphat](http://www.waywordradio.org/jumping-jehoshaphat/):

> - is the inspiration for the exclamation “jumpin’ Jehosaphat!” ***This alliterative idiom probably arose in the 19th century but was popularized by the cartoon character Yosemite Sam in the 20th century.***

(www.waywordradio.org)

Why is Jehoshaphat described as ***[jumping](http://www.midnightinamerica.net/docs/lit/a5l/a5l-jeh.htm)***?

> - It goes back to a prophecy which Israel’s king David uttered, explaining about how God works with people:
>
>   - *With the merciful You will show Yourself merciful;
>       With the blameless man You will show Yourself blameless;
>       With the pure You will show Yourself pure;
>       And with the devious You will show Yourself shrewd.
>       You will save the humble [afflicted] people;
>       But Your eyes are on the haughty, that You may bring them down.*

(2 Samuel 22:26-28)

> - That scripture is being fulfilled once again in our day in Iraq! But the above prophecy goes on:
>
>   - *For You are my lamp, O Lord;
>       The Lord shall enlighten my darkness.
>       For by You I can run against a troop;
>       **By my God I can leap over a wall.***

(2 Samuel 22:29-30)

> - And that’s what Jehoshaphat did, metaphorically speaking. He ‘jumped’ on that occasion because of the supernatural help of God.

Comment: The name itself means "the Lord has judged."